# Form validation returns incorrect value

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm trying to validate a simple form.

```
<form action="#">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" id="name"/>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

This is the code I'm using.

```
    var name = $('#name').val();

    $('form').submit(function(){
        checkForm();
    });

    function checkForm(){
        if(name === ''){
            $('#name').addClass('error');
            console.log('error');
        } else {
            $('#name').removeClass('error');
            console.log('success!');
        }       
    }
```

The problem is that the console logs 'error' every time, regardless of my input. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is updated only on page load when most probably the input is empty, after that when you update the input value that is not reflected in the name variable

Instead read the value of `name` field in the validation method, so that it will contain the updated value

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    //optional to prevent form submit
    return checkForm();
});

function checkForm() {
    //read the value of name field here
    var name = $('#name').val();
    if (name === '') {
        $('#name').addClass('error');
        console.log('error');
        //return false to notify that there is an error
        return false;
    } else {
        $('#name').removeClass('error');
        console.log('success!');
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Y5ZKY/)

Comment: Thanks that was the problem. But how come the addClass/removeClass works anyway?

Comment: @Operator that also was not working!!! I think in your case the page might be refreshed so you assumed that class was removed

Comment: Yeah that was the case! Thank you so much for all your great explanations! The return false in the if statement prevents the page from reloading if there's an error. Thanks again.

Comment: Sry, I have one more question. How come we need to return the function checkForm instead of just calling it to prevent the form submitting?

Comment: @Operator the `checkForm` method returns the valid status.. then to prevent the form submission the submit handler need to return false of have to call the `event.preventDefault()` -- see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Y5ZKY/2/

Comment: So the checkForm function doesn't return it's value unless we use the return statement?

Answer (score 1):

You did not passed the value of the name in the function named `checkForm()`.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var name = $('#name').val();
    checkForm(name);
});

function checkForm(name) {
  if (name === '') {
    $('#name').addClass('error');
    console.log('error');
  } else {
    $('#name').removeClass('error');
    console.log('success!');
  }
}
```